# 504 Gateway Timeout (UnknownError) when trying to track changes in a user's calendar

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

For our internal application we synchronize our user's calendars (in our Office 365 tenant) with a local "cache" in our database. We're using the new [Delta Queries](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_overview) in Microsoft Graph to do track these changes.

Most of the calendars synchronize correctly, but for some reason there is one single calendar where we consistently hit a `504 Gateway Timeout` error when attempting to request the events using the `nextLink` received from the first request.

**First request:**

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userId>/calendars/<calendarId>/calendarView/delta?startDateTime=2017-06-10t00%3A00%3A00Z&endDateTime=2018-06-10t00%3A00%3A00Z`

**First response:**

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(event)",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userId>/calendars/<calendarId>/calendarView/delta?$skiptoken=R0usmcdvmMuZCBYV0hguCGmIJqcU0n_6jVFWUlNKbXkBKYVlxLSMsISZI5sLLLJyLJF8hZIj0PURpAeP_XxydW_qbMUoFMTXjOpLa8Ta6rxMRA7Wv6IHYfjyLPcDzCbM_hKvTgq8BZaBeJv-a61mebF6X2wT4HqCAGL5lL4nLZabHk1nD9GbWJ0a4Qq0M41_GPYxEi5YNe9u1673SQ1Djw.F85xXB6GjtO7myCQCOgFvzp1G7mQB0BvuHQJyn0CICQ",
    "value": [
        <list of events>
    ]
}
```

**Second request:**

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userId>/calendars/<calendarId>/calendarView/delta?$skiptoken=R0usmcdvmMuZCBYV0hguCGmIJqcU0n_6jVFWUlNKbXkBKYVlxLSMsISZI5sLLLJyLJF8hZIj0PURpAeP_XxydW_qbMUoFMTXjOpLa8Ta6rxMRA7Wv6IHYfjyLPcDzCbM_hKvTgq8BZaBeJv-a61mebF6X2wT4HqCAGL5lL4nLZabHk1nD9GbWJ0a4Qq0M41_GPYxEi5YNe9u1673SQ1Djw.F85xXB6GjtO7myCQCOgFvzp1G7mQB0BvuHQJyn0CICQ`

**Second response:**

504 Gateway Timeout

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "0784cffb-cba7-424b-be1d-74b2bfef5da1",
            "date": "2017-07-10T09:11:33"
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried executing the script a few times over the last week, but the request consistently fails when using requesting the second page. Other calendars synchronize with no issues, so I don't really know how to debug these kind of issues. Is there anything we can do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to our attention, we are looking into your issue.

Comment: Hello @Trey, have you looked in to this problem? Could you give me an update?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with the team that owns Calendar sync to check where the latency in the stack is causing this time out. I'll post as soon as they have root caused this. I may need more info on what is special about this one Calendar encountering this issue.
Thanks,
Sri

Comment: Thank you for your response! Send me a PM if you need any more information about this specific calendar. I'm also willing to send you my work email so we can discuss this problem further using email.

Comment: Hi Sri, I was wondering if you could give me any update on the latency problems. Since I have reported this issue, the same issue has suddenly occured on another calendar within the same Office 365-tenant. Now we have two calendars who are refusing to sync properly.

Comment: Hello @Sri-MSFT, have you looked in to this problem? Could you give me an update?

Comment: Also waiting for the solution to this error. I';m getting the same 504 UnkownError

Comment: No solution for the gateway timeout issue. Only happens on some tenants, not others. Can't figure out why considering that some tenants have more items than the ones that fail. Would be useful to have Delta running instead of having to painstakingly run for each manually